# Assigning the value of another key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would just like to know how to access the value of another key in the same hash.
from inside the hash. not by doing myHash.key2 = myHash.key1....;
I mean a way of doing :

```
var myHash = {
    key1: 5,
    key2: key1 * 7,
    key3: true,
    key4: (key3)? "yes" : "no"
};
```

PS: this is only a simplified version of the actual code in fact every key has some complex operations inside. The values and not simple Numbers or bools.

Comment: use functions. ie for key2 would be `function() { return myHash.key1 * 7; }`

Comment: @r3wt That's a good idea but that would make me use () to access the values of these keys and not use them to access the values of the other ones. So if i wana iterate over the hash it wouldnt be easy. Unless i turn everything to functions. Any ideas on that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refer to other keys on the object within a literal definition.  The options for setting a key based on other keys or other values within the object are:

1. Use a getter function for the key that can return a value based on other properties.
2. Use a regular function for the key that can return a value based on other properties.
3. Assign a key/value outside of the literal definition where you can assign a static value based on the other keys/properties.

Here are examples of each of these options:

```
// use getters for properties that can base their values on other properties
var myHash = {
    key1: 5,
    get key2() { return this.key1 * 7; },
    key3: true,
    get key4() { return this.key3 ? "yes" : "no";}
};

console.log(myHash.key2);    // 35

// use regular functions for properties that can base 
// their values on other properties
var myHash = {
    key1: 5,
    key2: function() { return this.key1 * 7; },
    key3: true,
    key4: function() { return this.key3 ? "yes" : "no";}
};

console.log(myHash.key2());    // 35

// assign static properties outside the literal definition
// that can base their values on other properties
var myHash = {
    key1: 5,
    key3: true
};
myHash.key2 = myHash.key1 * 7;
myHash.key4 = myHash.key3 ? "yes" : "no";

console.log(myHash.key2);    // 35
```

Note: the first two options are "live".  If you change the value of `myHash.key1`, then the value of `myHash.key2` or `myHash.key2()` will change too.  The third option is static and the values of `myHash.key2` will not follow changes in `myHash.key1`.

Comment: @OlaviSau - you can't access another key in the middle of a literal definition?  The variable `myHash` is not set yet and `this` is not set to the object either.  So, you have no way to refer to other keys of the object from within a literal definition.  If you're going to do it in the literal definition, you have to use properties that are a function (either regular functions or getters).

Comment: Yeaaaah...just something odd happened, it worked in console the first time I tried, and then i tested one of your examples and then it didn't i must have missed something, I know what mistake I made now, I tried using this first, that created an obj and then the second time it used that object's var, you are indeed correct.

Comment: May want to use `Object.defineProperties` instead.

Comment: I think the getters would be the best option for me. because a function of the style : for(var key in myHash)console.log(myHash[key]); would work no matter if it's a function or not. any idea in terms of performance (speed)?

Comment: @AnthonyN. - I have not done a performance comparison on getters vs. static properties.  You could do one yourself fairly quickly in http://jsperf.com in your favorite browser.  Just remember that getters require IE9 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to refer to Object properties with the keyword `this`. Do this instead:

```
var myHash = {
  key1: 5,
  key2: 11,
  key3: true,
  isKey3true: function(){
    var r = this.key3 ? 'yes' : 'no';
    return r;
  }
}
myHash.key1 = 100;
console.log(key2); // key2 not a method
myHash.key3 = false;
console.log(myHash.isKey3true()); // method will review key3 value
```

Comment: `this.key1` in your example will be `undefined` and not reference the initial value 5.